# Iron-nickel phase in pallasite meteorites

Tags: geochemistry, mineralogy, meteorite, crystallography

I have recently been learning and researching about meteorite types and classification. Pallasites are mainly composed of a 'solid-solution' of olivine crystals and an iron-nickel alloy. My question is: what is the phase of the iron-nickel alloy, in a body-centered cubic crystal structure (alpha-iron, and hexahedrites) or face-centered cubic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a correction. A [solid solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_solution) is between different compositions in the same phase. For example, olivine is a solid solution of forsterite (Mg<sub>2</sub>SiO<sub>4</sub>) and fayalite (Fe<sub>2</sub>SiO<sub>4</sub>).

There are two common iron–nickel alloys found in meteorites (pallasites and others): kamacite and taenite. They are commonly intergrown into lamallae called "Widmanstätten pattern". It looks like this:

[image]

Kamacite has up to about 10% nickel, whereas taenite can get up to ~60% nickel, but commonly found up to 30%.

Kamacite has the space group Im3m, making it hexoctahedral body-centered. Taenite has the space group Fm3m, making it hexoctahedral face-centered.

Answer (score -1):

The metallic part ( essentially all two elements= Iron + nickel) is two phases mixed together : Body Centered Cubic - magnetic, and Face Centered Cubic - nonmagnetic. So the answer to your question is that it is both .  Iron ( BCC) starts to form FCC when Ni exceeds 6 %. The proverbial 18 - 8 stainless steel is 8 % Ni and generally non magnetic austenite phase. My educated guess is the classic  Widmidststten pattern is ferrite ( BCC ) grains/crystals forming from the original austenite ( FCC ) grains/crystals. But it is not that simple as when hot ( 1500 F ) it is 100 % austenite ( FCC ). Further complication is the austenite ( FCC , nickel rich) makes crystal twins . The twins can also give the Widmanstratten structure. And more complicated because temperature history can also affect the FCC / BCC morphology.  [ Maybe I cheated but I searched meteors on the net and learned some but also found some mistakes in the references. ]

Comment: The Widmanstattten pattern is due to exolution of taenite and kamacite.

Comment: Taenite and kamacite are the mineral  names for austenite  and ferrite ; aka , FCC and BCC.